# Change message header when Exception was thrown

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Inside MessageListener I throw exception. Default behaviour of message listener container is requeue message. My question - is it possible to change message headers when message was requeued?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot change a rejected message; you would have to publish a new message after the exception instead of rejecting it.

The framework [provides a mechanism to do that using a `RepublishMessageRecoverer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html#async-listeners), adding headers including the stack trace, but it doesn't let you add your own headers; you would need to subclass it to do that.

Comment: Thank you, Gary. I already did it this way. 
How are you think it is normal practice to mix messages rejecting for example 3 times and after that republish message to another error queue?

Comment: It depends on your requirements; sometimes the problem is a transient error and a retry might succeed. Other times it will always fail. You can change `maxAttempts` to 1 to force republish after the first failure. Or, you can configure the retry policy to only retry for certain exceptions and immediately call the recoverer otherwise. See `SimpleRetryPolicy`.